# How to evaluate $\sum_{\gcd (p,q)=1} \frac{1}{p^2q^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

How do find the following sum
$$
\sum_{\gcd (p,q)=1} \frac{1}{p^2q^2}
$$

Comment: \sum_{\gcd (p,q)=1} \frac{1}{p^2q^2} = 5/2

Comment: @zakariaID That's correct. Now I wonder what your question is when you already know the result. Do you want an explanation of how one obtains that result? Then state that in your question.

Comment: @DanielFischer I would like to say how one obtains it if that counts for anything.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's look at the more general case,

$$\sum_{\gcd (p,q) = d} \frac{1}{p^2q^2}.$$

$\gcd (p,q) = d$ means we have $p = d\cdot a$ and $q = d\cdot b$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, so we obtain

$$\sum_{\gcd(p,q) = d} \frac{1}{p^2q^2} = \sum_{\gcd(a,b) = 1} \frac{1}{(da)^2(db)^2} = \frac{1}{d^4}\sum_{\gcd(a,b) = 1} \frac{1}{a^2b^2}.$$

Now, any pair of positive integers occurs in exactly one of the sets $A_d = \{ (k,m) : \gcd(k,m) = d\}$, hence

\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{1}{d^4}\right)\left(\sum_{\gcd(p,q) = 1} \frac{1}{p^2q^2}\right)
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty \sum_{\gcd(a,b) = d} \frac{1}{a^2b^2}\\
&= \sum_{a,b \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}} \frac{1}{a^2b^2}\\
&= \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2.
\end{align}

Thus we obtain

$$\sum_{\gcd(p,q) = 1}\frac{1}{p^2q^2} = \frac{\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2}{\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{1}{d^4}} = \frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)} = \frac{\pi^4/36}{\pi^4/90} = \frac{90}{36} = \frac{5}{2}.$$

Comment: Not a big deal on the site, but for papers, you get a better look using Bigl and Bigr or one of the big derivations with l r specifications since the spacing is tighter. $$\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)$$ now with Bigl and Bigr $$\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)$$

Comment: I'm not sure if this is easily solved, but it's worth noting that the last sum equals the following product over prime $p$: $$\frac{(\prod_p\frac{p^2}{p^2-1})^2}{\prod_p\frac{p^4}{p^4-1}}$$ which simplifies to $$\prod_p \frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}$$Maybe there's an elementary way to show that that equals $\frac{5}2$ - it would be nice to avoid appealing to the zeta function.

Comment: Simply brilliant !

Comment: @Meelo Ramanujan considered that product, but I think he used the zeta function too.

Comment: The given answer is unimprovable !