# Question 11.15 Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory and got struck on this problem on page248 and need help.

[image]

I am trying general part not the part with 2 summations .

Attempt: Denoting $(m_1,..., m_r) $ by x I can write the summation in image as $\sum_{m_1}^{\infty} ... \sum_{m_r}^{\infty} I(x) {m_1}^{-s_1} ×... {m_r}^{-s_r}$  .

I can't think of anything else. I know I have worked myself only 1 line but I am at loss of ideas for this question and is struck badly.

So, it's my request to kindly help in proving it.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you do the first part with only two factors? If so, how?

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't tried that due to lack of time. Although I am self studying but I had other commitments and some other mathematical work to do.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am trying it now

Comment: @Daniel Fischer  I am not able to think after the same line as pointed above in the question.

Comment: A hint for the first: Try to show $$\zeta(4) \cdot \sum_{\substack{m,n = 1 \\ (m,n) = 1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^2n^2} = \zeta(2)^2\,.$$ When you understand how that works, the modifications to deal with the general case are easy.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am unable to show it. Can you please proof of 1st part as answer, that will really help me!

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022247/how-to-evaluate-sum-gcd-p-q-1-frac1p2q2)